# Problems with Kerning in Android Textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-fonts, kerning

---

I have an interesting thing (bug?) that i have run into while working with the TextView in Android.

I have a textview with the following attributes (clipped for brevity):

```
<TextView
    android::id="@+id/myId"
    android:text="Some Temporary Text 1234"
    android:textSize="7sp"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    ...
/>
```

This displays as expected **except the kerning is different** from a textview that sets these properties like this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) xxx.findViewByID(R.id.myId);
textView.setTextSize(7);
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
```

I was beating my head against a wall trying to figure out why when moving from building the view in code to XML the output was different.  It was hard to tell what was going on because I only had the one device attached.

So, I took a snapshot of the device with each method and used Photoshop to overlay the text onto each other.  **The text and font are identical** (i.e. I can line up letters pixel for pixel) **but the kerning** (the space between the letters) **was different!**

For that textview only, I switched to setting it in code instead of XML and compared again....and they are identical.

Here is a comparison of the two outputs.  The top is done in XML. The bottom is done in code.
[image]

**Edit:** Please note, the missing "INT" in the picture is just due to clipping of the picture when I captured the example.  The text strings are the same and the "INT" is present....just off the picture.

So there is definitely a difference there.  But notice the actual characters are the same.

Am I missing something in the XML?  I have searched for options surrounding kerning but aside form installing a custom font (which I don't want to do), I don't see a way to adjust the kerning in android.  Is there a way?  Is this a bug in android?

I can get around the issue but I was trying to eliminate the code as it is really out of place.

Comment: What happens when the text is *exactly* the same.  Right now you have " INT" at the end of the second string.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my end. Apart from being egregiously small, the text looks the same between both views.

Comment: @DavidCowden The text actually is exactly the same.  The INT is there, it is just cut off on the picture.  That was a bad move as it makes it look like it isn't the same.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way in Android to adjust the kerning directly.  A couple of suggestions, check the unit you are passing to TextView.setTextSize (int unit, float size) and check the width settings.  If you are using match_parent or fill_parent this could be messing with you.

Comment: @CoreyScott right I'm pretty sure Android doesn't respect the kerning pairs in font tables.  Reading the source it appears it does auto-kerning (explained in the Wikipedia article) but to my knowledge no one has observed this in practice.  The default unit for setTextSize is SP so there shouldn't be an issue there.  This is an interesting discovery.  My only thoughts are that the text could be getting set as a spannable with extra space or something when read from xml and that programmatically setting it using a char sequence instead of spannable is somehow different..

Comment: @DavidCowden That is a good thought.  If I get a chance, I will try to set the text using a spannable and see if I can recreate the kerning issue from code.  It won't solve my "I want to eliminate code" problem, but I am interested to know if that is what is going on.